# How to select "this" element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, this

In this parent div with `id=textList`, I have multiple text boxes and every time they are generating in multiple numbers with same `class=txt`. I want to get the value of the box which one user has clicked in; basically I want to select the current clicked text box.

```
<div id="textList">
    <input type="text" class="txt" value="">
    <input type="text" class="txt" value="">
    <input type="text" class="txt" value="">
    <input type="text" class="txt" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `this`? If you want to manipulate the selected input DOM element, you need to bind events, in this case focus event would do.

Comment: Also, seems like you are retrieving by class name, you should use ids instead.

Comment: You can usually just use the `this` keyword. What's the problem? How are you binding your event listener function? You haven't shown your JS. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: How do you generate text boxes?

Comment: @SankarRaj — Presumably with the HTML they included in their question.

Comment: @Quentin i am speaking about this _I have multiple text boxes and every time they are generating in multiple numbers with same class=txt_. That means number of textbox may increase. am i right?

Comment: This means which one I have clicked. Please forget about the text box, if i have <p> or <li> so how can I do it.

Comment: @SUMANDEBNATH — The answer will be *different* if you are using a `p` or an `li` instead of an `input`. Don't ask us to forget about the inputs if you want an answer that actually deals with them. You still haven't provided the [mcve] I asked for.

Comment: `this` is a js keyword. When you do `$(this).click` it the same keyword as in `this.on("click",...)`. I don't see the point of your question.

Comment: Use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: @dev8080 why are id's needed? Nothing wrong with using classes

Comment: @SankarRaj Yes, you are right, it will increase.

Comment: @Quentin If I use jQuery the code will be $(".txt").click(function(){$(this).value()}); Right? But I want to do same thing in pure JavaScript

Comment: @charlietfl I guessed the question was that the OP was using the class to get the currently focused element, but was getting multiple elements. But you were right. He could use class too.

Comment: @SUMANDEBNATH — So what's the problem? You do it the same way in your event listener. Or is your question really "How do I write an event listener without jQuery?"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get all elements by their class. Next you need to add an click listener to each of the elements. With the click listener's *event* parameter (`event.srcElement.value`) or via `this.value` you can access the value of the  Element

```
<div id="textList">
    <input type="text" class="txt" value="1">
    <input type="text" class="txt" value="2">
    <input type="text" class="txt" value="3">
    <input type="text" class="txt" value="4">
</div>
```

and JavaScript:

```
var inputElements = document.querySelectorAll(".txt");

for (var i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++) {
    inputElements[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        console.log(this.value);
    });
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ar1wzLva/

Comment: Why not use `this` as OP is asking? `event.srcElement === this`

Answer (score 1):

Attach any event like `keydown` or `click` and there use `this` to access the element to get value.

Here's the example for binding event,

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('txt');

for(var i = 0; i<inputs.length; i++){
  inputs[i].addEventListener("keyup", function(){
    console.log(this.value)
  }, false);
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('txt');
    
for(var i = 0; i<inputs.length; i++){
  inputs[i].addEventListener("keyup", function(){
    console.log(this.value)
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<div id="textList">
    <input type="text" class="txt" value="">
    <input type="text" class="txt" value="">
    <input type="text" class="txt" value="">
    <input type="text" class="txt" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: use keyup listener, else the problem is you pressed something, and select all , then delete, you will get prev value only.

Comment: Yes, you are right.. I used that event as a example. Looks like OP want to use `click` event.